# "expected unqualified-id before 'void'" & "string in class does not name a type" errors

Tags: c++, string, class

I'm not sure how to implement the solution here.

The errors at compilation are:-

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'void'

error: 'string' in class 'UserDirectory' does not name a type

error: 'string' in class 'UserDirectory' does not name a type
```

===========

```
**UserDirectory.cpp**

#include "UserDirectory.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

UserDirectory::UserDirectory(){
cout << "UserDirectory Constructor created\n\n";
}
UserDirectory::void setName(string x){
    name = x;
}
UserDirectory::string getName(){
    return name_;
}
UserDirectory::string name;
```

===========

```
**UserDirectory.h**

#ifndef USERDIRECTORY_H
#define USERDIRECTORY_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class UserDirectory
{
    public:
    UserDirectory();
    void setName( std::string x );
    std::string getName();
    private:
    std::string name_;
};

#endif // USERDIRECTORY_H
```

========

```
**main.cpp**

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "UserDirectory.h"
using namespace std;


int main(){

    UserDirectory user1;
string inputName;

cout << "Enter your name: ";
cin >> inputName;
user1.setName( inputName );
cout << "\nYou entered " << user1.getName();

    return 0;
} // end main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to define `name` separately, and you need to switch around the namespace and the type, like this:

```
void UserDirectory::setName(string x){
    name = x;
}
string UserDirectory::getName(){
    return name_;
}

// This would be necessary if "name" were static;
// Since it is not, remove this line:
string UserDirectory::name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dasblinkenlight - the scoping was I rookie mistake I know! I'll be sure not to make that again. 
I'll read up on my static/dynamic vars too.

Answer (score 3):

You're putting the `UserDirectory::` in the wrong place. The scope resolution operator (`::`) is used to resolve scoping on names. `void` and `string` don't need resolution as they're visible in that outer scope; only the names inside the class need scoping resolution, so it is applied to those names:

```
void UserDirectory::setName(string x){
    ...
}

string UserDirectory::getName(){
    ...
}
```

When you say `UserDirectory::void`, you're telling the compiler that there is a type `void` within your class `UserDirectory`, which there obviously isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too Chris, it has definitely helped clear up the scoping rules in my mind, seems obvious now.